# How to use Trycatch to skip errors in data downloading in R

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, try-catch, data-retrieval

I am trying to download data from the USGS website using the `dataRetrieval` package of R.

For that purpose, I have generated a function called `getstreamflow` in R that works fine when I ran for example.

```
siteNumber <- c("094985005","09498501","09489500","09489499","09498502")
Streamflow = getstreamflow(siteNumber)
```

The output of the function is a list of data frames
[image]

I could run the function when there is no issue downloading the data, but for some stations, I got the following error:

```
Request failed [404]. Retrying in 1.1 seconds...
Request failed [404]. Retrying in 3.3 seconds...
For: https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/site/?siteOutput=Expanded&format=rdb&site=0946666666
```

To avoid that the function stops when encounters an error, I am trying to use `tryCatch` as in the following code:

```
Streamflow = tryCatch(
  expr = {
    getstreamflow(siteNumber)
  }, 
  error = function(e) {
  message(paste(siteNumber," there was an error"))
})
```

I want the function to skip the station and go to the next when encountering an error. Currently, the output I got is the one presented below, that obviously is wrong, because it says that for all the stations there was an error:

```
094985005 there was an error09498501 there was an error09489500 there was an error09489499 there was an error09498502 there was an error09511300 there was an error09498400 there was an error09498500 there was an error09489700 there was an error09500500 there was an error09489082 there was an error09510200 there was an error09489100 there was an error09490500 there was an error09510180 there was an error09494000 there was an error09490000 there was an error09489086 there was an error09489089 there was an error09489200 there was an error09489078 there was an error09510170 there was an error09493500 there was an error09493000 there was an error09498503 there was an error09497500 there was an error09510000 there was an error09509502 there was an error09509500 there was an error09492400 there was an error09492500 there was an error09497980 there was an error09497850 there was an error09492000 there was an error09497800 there was an error09510150 there was an error09499500 there was an error... <truncated>
```

What I am doing wrong using the `tryCatch`?

Comment: You haven't described what goes wrong with your solution.

Comment: I just edited my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

You wrote the `tryCatch` outside of `getstreamflow`. Hence, if one site fails, then `getstreamflow` will return an error and nothing else. You should either supply 1 site at a time, or put the `tryCatch` inside `getstreamflow`.

**Example**

```r
x <- 1:5
fun <- function(x) {
  for (i in x) if (i == 5) stop("ERROR")
  return(x^2)
}

tryCatch(fun(x), error = function(e) paste0("wrong", x))
```

This returns:

> [1] "wrong1" "wrong2" "wrong3" "wrong4" "wrong5"

**Multiple arguments**

You indicated that you have both `siteNumber` and `datatype` to iterate over.

Using `Map`, we can define a function that takes two inputs:

```r
Map(function(x, y) tryCatch(fun(x, y), 
                            error = function(e) message(paste(x, " there was an error"))), 
    x = siteNumber, 
    y = datatype)
```

Using a for-loop, we can just iterate over them:

```r
Streamflow <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(siteNumber))
for (i in seq_along(siteNumber)) {
  Streamflow[[i]] <- tryCatch(getstreamflow(siteNumber[i], datatype), error = function(e) message(paste(x, " there was an error")))
}
```

Or, as suggested, just modify `getstreamflow`.

Comment: Thank you. I have one question if I want to supply one at a time but my function depends on two inputs (```siteNumber``` and ```datatype```). How Can I do it? I am doing like the following code ```PrecData = sapply(c(siteNumber,datatype), function(siteNumber,datatype) tryCatch(getweather(siteNumber,datatype), error = function(e) paste0("Error in station ", siteNumber)))```, but it is not working

Comment: I added some new examples, this time using `Map` and a for-loop.